Total disconection when using TorVPN in Csi Linux
I am using and giving a try in Csi Linux distro. She has TorVPN that, at least in theory, routes all the traffic through Tor Network. After service tor status commando I see the service is up. I tried several things, then I'll summarize. I modified a little DNS configurations as a clue of AI. Gone far from the target. Nevertheless, the connection is normal as not using TorVPN. Resuming, it has internet if TorVPN is out the game.

Ok, I just did some sourcery. I didn't know that I am using Csi Linux in Virtual Box (virtual machine) also did matter. Then I activated Tor service in host system, using sudo service tor start, and just that.
